# Issue with serial communication Arduino and python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino

I've some problem writing serial bytes from a python code to arduino.
The python code had to write to serial port a number that the arduino receive.

Python3 code:

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial ('/dev/ttyACM0',)
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.write(str(3).encode()) #or (b'3')
ser.write(str('\n').encode())
```

Arduino code:

```
void setup(){
Serial.begin (115200); //Comunicazione seriale 115200 bit
servomotore.attach(3);
pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
servomotore.write(180);
}
/*Il loop comprende due funzioni; sensori e Mappa, attivate ogni 15 gradi di movimento del servomotore, 
sensori rileva le distanze, Mappa invia i valori al seriale, ogni ciclo del radar produce 24 valori in centimetri*/
void loop() {
  char buffer[] = {' ',' '};
if (Serial.available() > 0) {


  Serial.readBytesUntil('n', buffer, 2);
  int incremento = atoi(buffer);
```

If I run this code I can't see output, no error or print, I need to exit with ctrl+c. Arduino doesn't receive nothing.
The Arduino code is longer, this is the only part that I can't understand in this moment, it's only a part of a most complex project

Comment: `readBytesUntil('n')` is never going to return if you never send a `n`!

Comment: Is this 'n' an EOF caracters? to indicate the end of line? How can I write this to serial in python?

Comment: You are specifying the literal letter `n`.  `\n` would be the newline character, which is more commonly used as a read terminator - but you're not sending that from the Python side, either.  To do so, you'd use  `serial.write()`, exactly as you did for the `3`.

Comment: I changed the code, but it  doesn't work, even with the /n, I can't understand why

Comment: Did you call `Serial.begin(115200)` in your Arduino setup function? You should show a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which means the setup part of the Arduino code as well as your loop code.

Comment: Okay, now you can see the setup, the entire project is bigger and the code is mostly about sensor and motors, the comments in the code are in Italian but they are not important for this issue (sorry for my english obviously). I can't understand why arduino doesn't receive anything, I tested previously the .ino code with the arduino serial monitor and everything works, but no way with pySerial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem. Here is how I tested it. On the Arduino Uno setup the following program:

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println(F("Serial test"));
}

char buffer[80] = { 0 };

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        Serial.print(F("read: ["));
        Serial.print(buffer);
        Serial.println("]");
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    }
}
```

The following python3 script successfully reads and writes to this Arduino firmware:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from serial import Serial

def main():
    ser = Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',)
    ser.baudrate = 115200

    print(ser.readline())

    ser.write(str(3).encode())
    ser.write(str('\n').encode())

    print(ser.readline())
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

I get the following output once the device is programmed and plugged in:

```
~ $ python3 so-check-serial.py 
b'Serial test\r\n'
b'read: [3]\r\n'
```

### Alternative interrupt based serial input

I'd like to add that I would not normally write a serial handler like this in Arduino. The following uses the serial interrupt to buffer the input and set a flag when the line is read completely. In this example we can wait or do other things until a whole line has been receivied (ie: keep blinking at the right times):

```
#include <Arduino.h>

volatile String buffer;
volatile bool inputComplete = false;

void serialEvent()
{
    while (Serial.available())
    {
        char c = (char)Serial.read();
        if (c == '\n')
            inputComplete = true;
        else
            buffer += c;
    }
}
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println(F("Serial test"));
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
}

void loop()
{
    if (inputComplete) {
        inputComplete = false;
        Serial.println(buffer.c_str());
        buffer = "";
    }
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, !digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));
    delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem looking at your code, the wrong code was in the arduino side, everything works properly!